# How can I stop Ruby from converting "\r\n" to "\n" when using File#readline?

Tags: ruby

My code works perfectly on Linux. When I move the code over to Windows, Ruby automatically converts all "\r\n" line endings to "\n" which makes all my strings one character too short, which in turn leads to errors when I use the line length for `File#seek` calls.

Rather than working around the issue by seeking by one extra character or converting the line endings back, I'd rather just prevent Ruby from changing them in the first place. Can that be done?

Comment: Can you try to open the file in binary mode?

Comment: Can you try `File.open('file', 'rb', :crlf_newline => true).read.lines` ?

Comment: @knut: That works. In fact, that's the workaround I'm currently using. My code fortunately already forces encoding based on the contents of the file so it works perfectly.

Comment: @ArupRakshit: [The docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/IO.html) don't mention the option `crlf_newline`. What does that do? Also, how do you even know of it? :-)

Comment: @Codemonkey I am aware of that. See [1](http://rubydoc.info/stdlib/core/String:encode) and [2](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/IO.html#method-c-new-label-Example+2). :-)

Comment: You're trying to seek on text files? That's not a good idea. Read your data into an array or small database, operate on the data, then output it again. You can control Ruby's idea of line-endings with the `$/` (AKA `$RS` AKA `$INPUT_RECORD_SEPARATOR`) variable.

Comment: @theTinMan: I'm using seek for parsing data files. When looking for the next data record, I'm using `readline` repeatedly until I find the line that starts a new data record, then I seek back to the start of the line, leaving the file in a state ready for a different function to parse the next record. Is this a bad idea? The data files are rather large, so I want to be able to iterate over data records directly from the disk rather than reading the whole file into memory.

Comment: If you're using fixed-length records, it's pretty safe to use seek. For variable-length records it's impossible to change the line's size without having to rewrite the rest of the file from that line to the end-of-file. For big text files, what you're doing will work, but it's not commonly done and instead I'd rely on reading them into a database, where I can take advantage of the DBM and indexes for rapid search, modify what I need to change, then write it all in a single pass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had assumed that the read mode "rb" would force "ASCII-8BIT" encoding of the input. Reading [the docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/IO.html#method-c-new-label-IO+Open+Mode) a bit closer, it turns out that I can both use the "rb" read mode to disable CRLF line endings and explicitly pass an internal and external encodings like normal.

In other words, a perfect solution with no extra work involved.